# When will Apple remove the methods/APIs marked as deprecated?

Tags: ios, deprecated, backwards-compatibility

When will Apple remove the methods/APIs marked as deprecated? After 2 or 3 releases after they were marked, or never?

Comment: When they feel like it.

Comment: They may keep them around for some specific number of versions, what that number is I don't know.

Comment: In general, the feature will be around as long as the "youngest" version where it was not deprecated is still supported.  But even that may not hold in the sense that a deprecated feature in version N may not work when also using a feature that is new in version N+M.  And keep in mind that if you use the feature in a version where it is deprecated, support in that version may disappear when the feature is pulled for later versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In common usage deprecation merely means that the feature is no longer recommended to be used and MAY be removed entirely in a later release.

[Wikipedia - Deprecation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation)

It is good practice to stop using deprecated features as soon as it is reasonable to, as you have no guarantee how long they will continue to be supported. Sometimes it could be as little as the next release or many dozens of versions later.

A quick search for Apple and Deprecation brought up this API reference where a feature has been deprecated but has survived at least one major OS revision.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html

So yeah, when will Apple remove them? Whenever they want to, so don't build stuff now that relies on them and move old code off of them as you can. The compiler will usually throw warnings when features that are being used have been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks! Especially for the sample, which Apple really removes a deprecated API after one major release.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree we should replace the deprecated API with their latest corresponding/substitute, however, it takes additional effort to keep the backward-compatibility, because most of the substitute APIs are only available from later iOS versions. Using a macro to make sure the different iOS uses different APIs can save the problem, but will make your code a mess. Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: Remember that was just one very quick example. I can imagine there are deprecated methods that have survived several major releases.

As for the what to do? Good question. I've got no nice answer as it isn't something I've had to deal with in my development life. I'd go searching to see what others have done before I take a guess.

Comment: The question was not, "What does deprecation mean in iOS and what should I do about it?", but rather when will they remove a deprecated method. This answer focuses on the first, unasked question and while it does provide a single example for the second, I'm not sure I would mark it as "correct" unless it at least provided a bigger sample and tried to extract a rule.