# What does "deprecated" really mean in iOS

Tags: ios, deprecated

In iOS development, deprecated methods can be used until they are "removed".

I understand deprecated methods are not suggested to be used but does that mean they might not work properly or can cause fatal problem?

Comment: they will only cause an issue if you use them in version `x.y` and they get removed in version `x.z`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691640/when-will-apple-remove-the-methods-apis-marked-as-deprecated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When will Apple remove the methods/APIs marked as deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691640/when-will-apple-remove-the-methods-apis-marked-as-deprecated)

Comment: it has not been defined; some of them functions on the same way as before; some of them returns dummy data or `nil` for every type of input; some of them could cause direct crash – the best practice is not to rely on such API after deprecation but to do a technical update and get them resolved as soon as possible when you ship a new version of your app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **What are deprecated methods:**
>
> Deprecated methods or classes that are outdated one which will eventually be removed.

Apple deprecates some methods/ classes, when they introduce a superior replacement, usually because they want to take advantage of new hardware, OS or language features (e.g. blocks) that were’t around when the original method was conceived.

> **When a deprecated method will be removed:**
>
> It depends according to the severity of method/property. For example:

```
cell.textColor
```

This property has been deprecated since iOS 3.0 and we can still use it. So unfortunately there's no any tight deadline of removing the stuff being deprecated.

Comment: The effect of deprecation is Apple destroys accumulated knowledge.  Google "how do I x in swift?" and there's a good chance that some of the answers will use deprecated methods.

Deprecation is extraordinarily frustrating to programmers who are new to IOS and to my eye, serves little purpose other than to stoke someone's ego. Your textColor example is a perfect example of "fixing" something that worked fine.